# Formal definition of a surface in the context of metric space.

Tags: differential-geometry

How can I formulate the concept of a parameterized surface within the context of metric spaces, that is, Given a metric space $ M $, determine the characteristics of a set $ S \subset M $, to be considered a surface.?

I'm reading about it, but I can't find a formal answer.

Also, how can I establish differentiability of a function $ f: S \to \mathbb {R} $?

Comment: I don't know a global definition of surfaces in general metrics spaces. I would say you can define a surface in a metric space to be a subset with Hausdorff dimension equal to 2. Otherwise, there exists in the context of differential geometry the following definition: a surface is a manifold of dimension 2. Differential geometry is the right context to talk about differentiability of functions.

Comment: @DIdier_ Can you write an answer where you detail your observations more to be able to read your ideas better.?

Comment: There is no further observation to write. Just look for "differential geometry" to have a smooth settings of manifolds and differentiability, and if you are looking for a more general but difficult setting, look for "Hausdorff dimension".

Comment: can I relate this wit the atlas?

Comment: The notion of atlas is part of the definition of a manifold in differential geometry.

Comment: Why do you think you can differentiate a function on a general metric space?